# What's the division rules of negative int numbers in haskell?

Tags: haskell, division, modulo

In GHCI, I get these results:

```
div (-7) ( 2) = -4
div ( 7) (-2) = -4
div (-7) (-2) =  3

mod ( 7)  ( 2) =  1
mod ( 7)  (-2) = -1
mod (-7)  ( 2) =  1
mod (-7)  (-2) = -1
```

and `div 4 (-3)` is `-2`, and `mod 4 (-3)` is `-2`.

I can't understand how to get those results. Is there some laws or rules?
 And what are right calculation steps ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it a good idea to first look at the documentation. For the `mod` function, we see:

> [**`mod :: a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod)
>
> integer modulus, satisfying
>
> ```
> (x `div` y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
> ```

So `` x `mod` y `` is calculated as:

```
mod x y = x - y * (div x y) -- logically equivalent definition
```

And:

> [**`div :: a -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div)
>
> integer division truncated **toward negative infinity**.

So in case the division is `-3.5`, the `div` will return `-4`.

So:

```
mod 7 2       = 7 - 2*(div 7 2)         = 7 - 2 * 3       = 7 - 6    = 1
mod 7 (-2)    = 7 - (-2)*(div 7 (-2))   = 7 - (-2) * (-4) = 7 - 8    = -1
mod (-7) 2    = (-7) - 2 * (div (-7) 2) = (-7) - 2 * (-4) = (-7) + 8 = 1
mod (-7) (-2) = (-7) - (-2) * (div (-7) (-2)) = -7 - (-2) * 3 = -7 + 6 = -1
```